# "Encode" all $n$-permutations with the fewest number of swaps

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, computer-science, coding-theory

The goal is to find $m$ swaps $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_m$ such that any $n$-permutation can be encoded as a binary sequence of length $m$, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m$, where $x_i$ indicates whether to perform the $s_i$ swap (if $x_i=1$) or skip it (if $x_i=0$).

For example, if we list the swaps as $s_1=(1,2),\; s_2=(2,3),\; s_3=(3,1)$, then the permutation from $ABC$ to $CAB$ can be encoded as $1,0,1$: first swap the $(1,2)$ elements to get $BAC$, then skip the swap of $(2,3)$ elements because $x_2=0$, and finally swap the $(3,1)$ elements to get $CAB$. Is there a way to make $m$ as small as possible (perhaps as close as possible to $\log_2{n!}$) while ensuring that every $n$-permutation can be represented?

Background information: This problem stems from my attempt to construct a "permutation circuit". This circuit accepts $n$ elements as input and produces a permutation of these elements as output. The circuit exclusively utilizes a component known as a "swap" gate. This gate takes two elements as input and is controlled by an additional input bit. If this bit is set to $1$, the gate swaps the two input elements before outputting them. If the bit is set to $0$, the gate outputs the input elements directly without swapping. My goal is to construct such a circuit using the fewest possible number of these gates, enabling it to generate any permutation of these $n$ elements.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J100l.png)

Comment: Are you free to choose the sequence of transpositions however you like? Is the particular order that you listed $s_1$, $s_2$, and $s_3$ arbitrary?

Comment: Also, must the transpositions be distinct? For example in $S_3$, can I choose this sequence of Coxeter generators (swapping adjacent elements): $s_1, s_2, s_1$, where $s_1 = (1\;2)$ and $s_2 = (2\;3)$?

Comment: @SammyBlack Thank you for your reply. Regarding your first question, the order of the swaps is fixed. You can only choose to perform or skip a swap in sequence, but you cannot change their order (if changing the order is allowed, performing $s_1$​ then $s_3$​ and performing $s_3$​ then $s_1$​ would both result in the same encoding of $1,0,1$). For your second question, similar to the first, you cannot reuse $s_i$, however, you can let $s_i=s_j$ for different $i$ and $j$.

Comment: @SammyBlack My explanation may not be very easy to understand (sorry for my poor English), I have added some background information in the problem description, which may help you understand my meaning.

Comment: Your English is perfect, and I find your explanation quite understandable. Complete enumeration shows that the minimal $m$ for $n=2,3,4,5$ is $1,3,5,8$, respectively. This is as close as possible to $\log_2n!$ except that $5!=120$ is quite close to $2^7=128$ and there’s no solution with $m=7$. Complete enumeration doesn’t seem feasible for $n\ge6$.

Comment: [Here’s the Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4880379.java) I used for the enumeration.

Comment: [Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4880379SimulatedAnnealing.java) that finds near-optimal solutions for $n=6,7,8$ with $m=11,14,17$, respectively, in each case just one more than required by the $\log_2n!$ bound and significantly better than $\binom n2=15,21,28$ from bubble sort. The swaps are

$$(15)(53)(21)(64)(62)(34)(65)(24)(31)(53)(43)\;,\\(34)(16)(27)(15)(64)(35)(17)(62)(73)(51)(65)(24)(34)(21)\;,\\(45)(83)(26)(17)(21)(23)(48)(67)(68)(51)(47)(52)(13)(73)(46)(82)(54)\;.$$

Unfortunately I don’t see any patterns.

Comment: So it seems that a solution of order $\log_2n!$ is possible, but I don’t see a more systematic approach than combinatorial optimization to find one. What sort of $n$ do you need this for?

Comment: @joriki, thank you for your efforts and the code you've provided. It's encouraging to see results that closely align with what was anticipated, which offer a valuable perspective. However, in practical circuits, the scale of $n$ often reaches into the thousands, so I guess that brute force solutions may not be applicable in such scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this is helpful. Joriki's brute force calculations of minimal $m$ for small $n$ are quite interesting and indeed come close to your estimate of $\log_2(n!)$. If you're willing to sacrifice such efficiency in exchange for a simpler, algorithmic design, here's an alternative approach, following a well-trodden path. The number of bits is $m = \binom{n}{2} = \frac12 n(n-1)$.

##### Coxeter presentation of $S_n$

There's a well-known presentation of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $n$ symbols given by the $n-1$ Coxeter generators $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{n-1}$, where $\sigma_i = (i\;\;i+1)$. Besides being involutions ($\sigma_i^2 = 1$), distant (non-consecutive) generators commute ($\sigma_i\sigma_j = \sigma_j\sigma_i$ for $|i - j| > 1$) and consecutive generators ($|i - j| = 1$) satisfy the braid relation
$$
\sigma_i\sigma_j\sigma_i = \sigma_j\sigma_i\sigma_j. 
$$

##### Example for $n = 3$

The two generators are $\sigma_1 = (1\;2)$ and $\sigma_2 = (2\;3)$, and the $3! = 6$ elements of $S_3$ can be presented as words formed of these "swaps":
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{one-line} & \text{cycle} & \text{word} \\
\hline
123 & - & \\
213 & (1\;2) & \sigma_1 \\
132 & (2\;3) & \sigma_2 \\
231 & (1\;2)(2\;3) & \sigma_1\sigma_2 \\
312 & (2\;3)(1\;2) & \sigma_2\sigma_1 \\
321 & (1\;2)(2\;3)(1\;2) & \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1 \\
\end{array}
$$

The lengths of these words are minimal, and I sorted them by len-lex order. Notice, there's just one permutation of length $3$, called the [longest element](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Longest_element_of_a_Coxeter_group), and it determines the length of the sequence needed for your encoding:
$$
m = \binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} 
$$
since each symbol, thinking in the one-line notation, has to swap with each other symbol to form the permutation to completely reverses the sequence $(123 \mapsto 321)$.

So you could define your sequence of transpositions by this longest word: $\sigma_1^{s_3} \sigma_2^{s_2} \sigma_1^{s_1}$, where each $s_i \in \{0, 1\}$ and the composition of permutations is read from right to left as usual. But I think it's more natural to record the encoding as a string, read from left to right. (These conventions are arbitrary, and reversing just swaps out each permutation for its inverse):
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
1\text{-line} & \text{word} & \text{verbose} & \text{encoding} \\
\hline
123 & - & \sigma_1^0\sigma_2^0\sigma_1^0 & 000 \\
213 & \sigma_1 & \sigma_1^1\sigma_2^0\sigma_1^0 & 001 \\
132 & \sigma_2 & \sigma_1^0\sigma_2^1\sigma_1^0 & 010 \\
231 & \sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_1^1\sigma_2^1\sigma_1^0 & 011 \\
312 & \sigma_2\sigma_1 & \sigma_1^0\sigma_2^1\sigma_1^1 & 110 \\
321 & \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1 & \sigma_1^1\sigma_2^1\sigma_1^1 & 111 \\
\end{array}
$$

#### Why does this work?

Beginning with a permutation in one-line notation, use a bubble sort algorithm to return the sequence to ascending order. Begin with the largest symbol $n$, and record the transpositions required to send it "home" (position $n$), then move on to the next largest symbol $n-1$, again recording transpositions needed to send it to position $n-1$. Continue all the way down. If we're recording these as a sequence of permutations in the usual function notation, then we record this sequence from right-to-left.

Here's an example of this process with the longest element $4321$ in $S_4$:
$$
\color{blue}{43}21 \overset{\sigma_1}{\mapsto} 
3\color{blue}{42}1 \overset{\sigma_2}{\mapsto} 
32\color{blue}{41} \overset{\sigma_3}{\mapsto} 
\color{blue}{32}14 \overset{\sigma_1}{\mapsto} 
2\color{blue}{31}4 \overset{\sigma_2}{\mapsto} 
\color{blue}{21}34 \overset{\sigma_1}{\mapsto} 
1234 
$$
From right to left, this is the word
$\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1$
which is of length $\binom{4}{2} = 6$, as expected.

What about for all the other permutations? At each stage, we're swapping a pair of symbols from decreasing to increasing order, recording a $1$ as it moves to the right. If a pair of symbols are already in increasing order, then we simply omit that swap, and record a $0$. As a consequence, for any permutation, the sequence of swaps will always be a subsequence of the longest word. For $n = 4$, this will be encoded as $s_1s_2s_3s_4s_5s_6$, where the permutation is presented as
$$
\sigma_1^{s_6} \sigma_2^{s_5} \sigma_1^{s_4} \sigma_3^{s_3} \sigma_2^{s_2} \sigma_1^{s_1}.
$$
The general patter should be clear.

##### Encoding for $n = 4$

To illustrate that this is indeed algorithmic, here are the results generated by a dozen or so lines of Python code for $n = 4$. As before, I've sorted the permutations by their encodings, first by length (total number of instances of $1$) then lexicographically.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\text{one-line} & \text{encoding} & \text{length} \\
\hline 
1234 & 000000 & 0 \\
2134 & 000001 & 1 \\
1324 & 000010 & 1 \\
1243 & 001000 & 1 \\
2314 & 000011 & 2 \\
3124 & 000110 & 2 \\
2143 & 001001 & 2 \\
1342 & 001010 & 2 \\
1423 & 011000 & 2 \\
3214 & 000111 & 3 \\
2341 & 001011 & 3 \\
3142 & 001110 & 3 \\
2413 & 011001 & 3 \\
1432 & 011010 & 3 \\
4123 & 111000 & 3 \\
3241 & 001111 & 4 \\
2431 & 011011 & 4 \\
3412 & 011110 & 4 \\
4213 & 111001 & 4 \\
4132 & 111010 & 4 \\
3421 & 011111 & 5 \\
4231 & 111011 & 5 \\
4312 & 111110 & 5 \\
4321 & 111111 & 6 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: As you pointed out this uses only transpositions of two adjacent entries. In terms of algorithms that amounts to constraining oneself to so called *bubble-sorting*. In Shell sorting we also use more "distant" transpositions (but still in somewhat constrained way).

Answer (score 4):

Any comparison-based [oblivious sorting algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/58031/755) that uses $m$ comparisons immediately leads to a solution to your problem with $m$ swaps.  So your problem amounts to asking for a comparison-based oblivious sorting algorithm with the best possible running time.

A standard way to build an oblivious sort is using a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network).  There are many constructions of sorting networks.  Constructing sorting networks of optimal size is an open problem.  If you want a simple construction, you might look at [Batcher's odd-even mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort) or [bitonic mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) or [Parberry's pairwise sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_sorting_network).  These have size $m=O(n \log^2 n)$ (in some cases with very small constant factor, e.g., about 1).  Compare to a [straightforward lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) on the optimal size, namely, $m \ge \log_2 n! = n \log n - \Theta(n)$.

Also relevant: [Zig-zag sort](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2777) achieves size $O(n \log n)$, which is within a constant factor of optimal, but is very complicated and might have large constant factors hidden in the big-O notation.  Finally, [bucket oblivious sort](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611976014.2) and other recent related research might be of interest to you.